# Why the same http request works in browser and fails when sent from my Android app?

Tags: php, android, httprequest, directus

I'm trying to fetch jSON data from Directus Api and requests are working fine when made from the browser. However, when I send the very same requests from my android app (identical URLs, with 'Authorization' header or with parameters) - the requests fail with
**java.io.FileNotFoundException** and response code 405.

**The URL with parameters: WORKS IN BROWSER**

http://example.com/dev/public/_/items/cities/1?access_token=my_test_token

**The same request with parameters: FAILS IN ADNROID**

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.appendQueryParameter("access_token","my_test_token");
//..
URL url = new URL(serverURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
conn.addRequestProperty("Accept","application/json; charset=utf-8");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();
```

**The URL without parameters, sent with header 'Authorization: Bearer my_test_token': WORKS IN BROWSER**

http://example.com/dev/public/_/items/cities/1

**The same request with 'Authorization: Bearer my_test_token' header: FAILS IN ANDROID**

```
URL url = new URL(serverURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
conn.addRequestProperty("Accept","application/json; charset=utf-8");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();
```

Non of the above requests (with parameters or with 'Authorization') work in Android. Is there any difference between browser and Android requests? Why the same request fails on Android giving **java.io.FileNotFoundException** but works in the browser? Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What does the server returns in the `Allow` header since it is a 405 error ?

Comment: is that ure complete java code ?  show the how you get an output stream to write on the `conn`.

Comment: Yes, above comments are spot on. I've figured out that I was using POST and trying to send output stream when allowed method was GET so the server returned 405 'methodNotAllowed'. I focused too much on the java.io.FileNotFoundException and missed it. Thank you for taking time to look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that I was using POST and trying to send output stream when allowed method was GET so the server returned 405 'methodNotAllowed'.